# Fetch Data Into Split Database?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access database which permits users (via VBA under a button) to FETCH data from a SQL Server into their local instance.  Currently, this creates a new table in the same AccessDB containing my app.

Due to some potentially large table sizes, I'd like to FETCH these large tables into a backend database local to the user, then LINK to them in my frontend app.

The following is a snippet of how I fetch currently:

```
    strSQL = "SELECT dbo_TblMatched.*, * " & _
        "INTO TblMatched FROM dbo_TblMatched " & _
        "WHERE dbo_TblMatched.invID= " & myInvID
    db.Execute strSQL
```

Question:  Initiated from the fontend app, can I direct the "INTO" portion of this command to send the data to the backend database (already exists)?  I have no issue LINKING once the tables reside in the backend database.

Note:  There are only 3 large/static tables I want to split out like this.  The remainder of tables I'd prefer to keep local to the frontend.

Thanks!

Comment: In the Access database where you're doing this, make `TblMatched` a link to a pre-created table in your secondary Access database.  Then you can execute an "append query" (`INSERT INTO ...`) to fetch data from the server and store it in the linked Access table.

Comment: @HansUp.  I did consider this idea.  My current issue is these tables are deleted and replaced as users move from job to job throughout the day.  I suppose I could EMTPY the linked tables vs DROPPING them...  Something to try.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, Mark.  I see no reason to drop and then recreate `TblMatched` repeatedly.  Create it once.  Thereafter when you want to load fresh data into it, execute `DELETE FROM TblMatched;` followed by `INSERT INTO TblMatched (<target fields>) SELECT <source fields> FROM dbo_TblMatched;`

Comment: Yep, that's kind of what I tried to describe in my reply ;-).   Just tested-These huge linked tables empty almost immediately - will be as ~transparent to user as DROP is today.

Comment: Note too that any DDL action in your back end is going to disrupt any other users actively connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to another database in an SQL statement by prepending a connection string in brackets before the desired remote object.

For an access database it would look like this:

```vba
strSQL = " SELECT dbo_TblMatched.*, *" & _
         "   INTO [;DATABASE=<path_to_accdb>].TblMatched" & _
         "   FROM dbo_TblMatched" & _
         "  WHERE dbo_TblMatched.invID = " & myInvID
```

Is this what you had in mind?